# What is this open space on rear exterior wall of my house called?

Tags: exterior

What is this area called on the rear of the house? Almost like an extension where the kitchen sink is. Can that be blocked to prevent cold air from blowing up through there?

[image]

Comment: Can you step back and take another picture capturing more of the detail of that corner of the house with respect to the rest of the building. It may also be helpful if you could add a picture from underneath the overhang looking up at an angle (it may require adding some additional lighting under there to get a decent picture).

Comment: summer kitchen ?

Comment: "Cantilevered bump out"?

Comment: Needs rodentproofing to keep the insulation in and the rodents out. If there are drafts, there are critters...

Answer (score 1):

To prevent heat loss and cold air entry, you can insulate the bottom of that overhang from underneath.

You could probably attach 2" XPS to the bottom, seal all gaps with expanding foam, and apply cladding (painted plywood) to mechanically attach the foam board and protect it. No framing needed, and the entire assembly will be a few inches thick.

It is important to avoid ground contact, and provide ample space for air ventilation between that bottom and the ground including (if applicable) any melting snow.

[image]

Depending on the amount of rain in your area, you could consider a drip edge at the bottom of the current (white) siding so that no water running down on the siding, whether from the face of the siding or from behind it (!), can seep into the new insulating sandwich. (Your picture does not show how much the siding overhangs the bottom, but you can of course easily check this). Ideally, attach and seal a drip edge to the sheathing of the floor/wall/rim-joist behind the siding. It does not need a protruding drip lip, as long as it drops past the protective plywood.

This will provide the heat improvement you seek without introducing additional problems such as water ingress & rot, an inviting living space for rodents and a dark warm moist chamber for molds to grow.